# How to stop a Windows Forms Button being clicked twice

Tags: .net, winforms, button

I've got a Windows Forms Button on a Form which submits a web request. I want to be able to disable the button when it is first clicked and then re-enable it when I get a response. I don't have much control over the code that is being called and how it is being called so all I can play around with are Button events or I can create my own button that inherits from Button like so:

```
public class SingleClickButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        bool wasEnabled = this.Enabled;
        this.Enabled = false;

        if (wasEnabled)
        {
            base.OnClick(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have to call the base OnClick method last as the button won't disable until the web request has completed.

The problem I am having is that if the user does click multiple times the click events seem to build up and are all still executed. Is there maybe a way to cancel all queued events? Or is there a far simpler solution to my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need use this scenario:

```
public class SingleClickButton : Button
{
        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
                this.Enabled = false;
                RunAsynchronousMethod( CallBack );
                base.OnClick(e);
        }

        void CallBack()
        {
                this.Enabled = true;
        }
}
```

The "RunAsynchronousMethod" can create new "Thread" or use "ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem)".

**EDIT:**

```
public class SingleClickButton : Button {
        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) {
                this.Enabled = false;
                RunAsynchronousMethod( CallBack );
                base.OnClick(e);
        }

        void CallBack() {
                this.Enabled = true;
        }

        void RunAsynchronousMethod( Action callBack ) {
                // there you can use ThreadPool or Thread
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( this.Worker, callBack );
        }

        void Worker( object callBack ) {
                try {
                    // some operations
                }
                finally {
                    // after operations was proceeded, the callback function will
                    // be called
                    ((Action)callBack)();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, Callback is the method where all the work happens? If so calling this.Enabled inside it will cause a cross thread error.

Comment: No, Callback function is called AFTER the work is done. Look at my edit, for details.

Comment: You should use a Invoker to re-enable the button

Answer (score 1):

First I implemented the @TcKs answer what helped me a lot but the "gray button" get me some issues. (some users thought that the system had a problem)
So I make a small change to only ignore the subsequent clicks.

```
bool ignoreClick = false;
protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
{
        // Prevent DoubleClick
        if (ignoreClick) return;
        ignoreClick = true;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.Worker);
        base.OnClick(e);
}
void Worker(object obj)
{
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);                
         }
         catch { }
         ignoreClick = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with enabling and disabling the button is that if what you have in the click event runs so fast that the button get enabled before the second click of the double click action (some users don't understand that it only takes 1 click) so here is my solution.

```
private const int waittime = 2;
private DateTime clickTime = DateTime.Now;

private void cmd_TimeStamp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if ((DateTime.Now - clickTime).Seconds < waittime)
    return;
  else
    clickTime = DateTime.Now;
  try
  {
    cmd_TimeStamp.Enabled = false;
    //Do some stuff in here
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Show error if any
    MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
  finally
  {
    cmd_TimeStamp.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Solved it by adding a timer to the form, then using that timer to reenable the button which I disable on the click event.

```
    private void btnPrintReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPrintReport.Enabled = false;
        timerEnablePrint.Enabled = true;
        BackgroundProcess.Add("Printing", new WaitCallback(generateReport), null);
    }


    private void timerEnablePrint_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPrintReport.Enabled = true;
        timerEnablePrint.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Set the timer to a sensible interval.  I use 4 seconds (it's just to avoid users doubleclicking)

Comment: And what happens, when the operation take more than 4 seconds :)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps disable the button until the processing is done?